# ffmpeg add ad audio file to a original audio file at start and before end

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

i have a ad.mp3 file which have a ad audio file, and i have a original mp3 audio file where i want to merge with ad file at the start of original file and before end

i have install ffmpeg to my ubuntu system and i have use below code but this is make every times

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp3 -filter_complex "amovie=ad.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB[beep];[0][beep]amix=duration=shortest,volume=2" output.mp3
```

my requirement is to add ad.mp3 at start of original.mp3 and before end

please help me how to solve this issue..

Answer (score -1):

try ffmpeg -i "concat:input1.mp3|input2.mp3|input3.mp3" -c copy output.mp3